# iOS Apps must include 64-bit Support

Tags: objective-c, 64-bit, zxing

As for the **1. Feb 2015** it is a requirement that Apps must include 64-bit support. For now i have the following configuration for my project: `${ARCHS_STANDARD_32_BIT}` for Architectures and for Valid Architectures i have `armv7 armv7s`. If i understand it correctly i can change both to `${ARCHS_STANDARD}` now correct ?

Now i'm also using ZXing which is a library for scanning barcodes. After changing these settings i'm getting a lot of errors for ZXing like `"Implicit conversion loses integer precision: 'unsigned long' to 'int'"`.

Is it possible to change my target's settings to 64 bit but leave the library as it is 32 bit? Or will this not work. If not i guess i either have to fix these errors myself or replace the library.

Comment: I think the best approach is to download 64 bit version of ZXing library, if there isn't, you can download the source code and make a 64 bit library from it.

Comment: I think ZXing for iOS is no longer maintained.

Comment: Really? It is said that from iOS 7 there is a build-in barcode scan functionality, which you can use if you only support iOS 7 and above.

Comment: ZXing is not retiring, [ZXingObjC](https://github.com/TheLevelUp/ZXingObjC)'s example applications are using the 64-bit setting.

Comment: I'm using the ZXingWidget. I think your referencing to a different library. Here is the link: [ZXing retired](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zxing/L2oGZllqwXI)

Comment: I ended up dropping the library and just used the built-in capabilities with iOS7.